# Generating Polygon Mesh From Control Points of Bezier Patch

Tags: graphics, bezier

I wanna make program on Bézier surfaces, I found on internet [this article](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/cs563/talks/surface/bez_surf.html), there is one approach how to do It, but I don't understand second step definitely and third step particularly. Or may be I just cant imagine what author can mean by that.

```
B. Use blending tables to calculate points in "row curve":

for( u = 0; u < 10; u++ )
{
    blend row 0 control points -> new control point
    blend row 1 control points -> new control point
    blend row 2 control points -> new control point
    blend row 3 control points -> new control point

    for( v = 0; v < 10; v++ )
    {
        blend 4 new control points -> point on surface
    }
}
C. Generate edges and polygons from grid of surface points.
```

Can anyone explain what I could mean? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

A Bezier-surface is a bezier-curve, where the control-points are moving along other Bezier-curves, instead of being stationary.

```
B(0,u) = (1-u)^3
B(1,u) = 3*u*(1-u)^2
B(2,u) = 3*u^2*(1-u)
B(3,u) = u^3

C[0..3, 0..3] = control points

Curve(t,C0,C1,C2,C3) = B(0,t)*C0 + B(1,t)*C1 + B(2,t)*C2 + B(3,t)*C3

Surface(s,t,C[0..3,0..3]) =
    Curve(t, Curve(s, C[0,0], C[1,0], C[2,0], C[3,0]),
             Curve(s, C[0,1], C[1,1], C[2,1], C[3,1]),
             Curve(s, C[0,2], C[1,2], C[2,2], C[3,2]),
             Curve(s, C[0,3], C[1,3], C[2,3], C[3,3]))
```

These functions samples the curve (or surface) for specific values of `t` (and `s`).

The article talks about caching the values of the Bernstain polynomials (the `B(i,u)` function) before calculating the sums. This is so you don't have to recalculate it each time.

It then goes on talking about subdivision. This involves breaking the four control points in each curve into two groups of four. Each group will trace half the original curve.

Advancing this into surfaces, you break each row-curve into two, and then each column-curve into two. This will give you four surfaces tracing part of the original curve.

Subdivision is generally quicker than sampling the curve/surface.

```
SplitCurve(C0,C1,C2,C3) = [
    C0,                           # First control-point of first sub-curve
    (C0 + C1)/2,                  # Second control-point of first sub-curve
    (C0 + 2*C1 + C2)/4,           # Third control-point of first sub-curve
    (C0 + 3*C1 + 3*C2 + C3)/8,    # Shared first/last control-point
    (C1 + 2*C2 + C3)/4,           # Second control-point of second sub-curve
    (C2 + C3)/2,                  # Third control-point of second sub-curve
    C3                            # Fourth control-point of second sub-curve
]

SplitSurface(C[0..3,0..3]) =
    col0 = SplitCurve(C[0,0], C[0,1], C[0,2], C[0,3])
    col1 = SplitCurve(C[0,0], C[0,1], C[0,2], C[0,3])
    col2 = SplitCurve(C[0,0], C[0,1], C[0,2], C[0,3])
    col3 = SplitCurve(C[0,0], C[0,1], C[0,2], C[0,3])
    return [
        SplitCurve(col0[0], col1[0], col2[0], col3[0]),
        SplitCurve(col0[1], col1[1], col2[1], col3[1]),
        SplitCurve(col0[2], col1[2], col2[2], col3[2]),
        SplitCurve(col0[3], col1[3], col2[3], col3[3]),
        SplitCurve(col0[4], col1[4], col2[4], col3[4]),
        SplitCurve(col0[5], col1[5], col2[5], col3[5]),
        SplitCurve(col0[6], col1[6], col2[6], col3[6])
    ]
```

Continue to subdivide each sub-surface, until all control points lies within the same pixel. Here "pixel" refers to the projected curve. To check this, the naïve way would be to project each control point to screen coordinates.

To create triangle-meshes, you can subdivide the control-points some fixed number of times, then pick the top-left control point of each surface.