# Image warp with 2D bezier surface

Tags: image-processing

Does anyone know of an implementation of a 2D Bezier Surface? If you look at [this link](http://fatlinesofcode.philipandrews.org/2011/02/20/warping-bitmaps-with-a-bezier-surface/), the author uses a flash library that does this for him. I want to do the same, except I need to do my own implementation which takes a regular image, and transforms it to the bezier surface.

His implementation, I believe, maps to a geometric mesh of triangles which are used to distort the image. According to [this link](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/cs563/talks/surface/bez_surf.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887782/generating-polygon-mesh-from-control-points-of-bezier-patch), if you break it down until you get a pixel-level mapping then the quality is improved at the sake of speed. Ultimately I'm interested in the highest quality, so sacrificing speed is OK.

Would anyone know any such implementation? I'm going to be writing it in C#, but any Java/C++/C/Py/pseudo code would be greatly appreciated - been looking for days now!